# Equal height panels?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, multiple-columns, rows

I'm trying to make a panel on the right, to be equal height of two panels on the left that are on top of each other.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0PxA.png

I have tried using .row-eq-height css, but it wouldn't stretch the panels themselves.

```
<!--  Row #2 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!--  Information panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default -->">

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <p class="panel-title">Information</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4 id="numVal">Value: 0</h4>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--  Secondary box -->
                <div class="panel panel-default secondPanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <p class="panel-title">Box2</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--  Main panel -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default mainPanel">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm still new to all of this, so please bear with me! And i'd appreciate some help! Thank you!

EDIT: CSS:https://pastebin.com/7RXYYH3w Sorry i didn't include it before!

Comment: Please include your CSS so we can better help you with this.

Comment: Added it now, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked it a bit and added the display: flex to the outer container. That seems to do what you are after.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row container-fluid" style="display:flex">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!--  Information panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="panel-title">Information</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h4 id="numVal">Value: 0</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--  Secondary box -->
            <div class="panel panel-default secondPanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="panel-title">Box2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  Main panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default mainPanel col-md-8">
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just one more question, if you don't mind! The main panel has slight overhead in width from the right, yet the other two panels are the same, how did that happen? http://i.imgur.com/qhRdXn3.png

Comment: It's the same in my version. So there could be two reasons. the fact that the left panel is nested in another div, while the right one isn't, or you have some css that is affecting it. I would suggest using the developer tools (F12) to see where the difference lies. It is a good idea to get used to these tools anyway

Comment: .mainPanel {margin-right: 15px;} works well enough for me i guess, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the height using Flexbox properties. 
Here is what I think you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33186/

```
.row-eq-height{
  display: flex;
}
.take-up-space{
  flex:1;
}

.flex-column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Also, here is a good way to get started on Flexbox in general: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/